# Java - Scanner Error & printing error

Tags: java, eclipse, compiler-errors

My java code is supposed to:

Write a Java program that reads a sequence of student records and prints the total score for each student. Each record has the student’s first and last name, followed by a sequence of test scores and a sentinel of –1. The sequence is terminated by the word END.
Here is a sample sequence:

Harry Morgan 94 71 86 95 -1

Sally Lin 99 98 100 95 90 -1

END

Please not:

Hint: you need nested loops

For part C, use what we have covered ONLY. Don’t use arrays, you don’t have to save your values.

My code (not sure if correct or not):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class PartC {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String name;
    int score = 0;
    int totalS = 0;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter first, last name: ");
    name = input.next();
    if(name.equals("END"))
    {
        while(score != -1)
        {
            System.out.print("Enter a score: ");
            score = input.nextInt();
            totalS = (totalS+score);
        }
        System.out.print(name + " " + score);
        System.out.print("total is: " + totalS);
```

The problem is that it keeps giving me errors, and I'm not too sure how to print out the scores right after each other (like 94 71 86 95):

```
Enter first, last name: Harry Morgan
Enter a score: Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
at PartC.main(PartC.java:18)'
```

thank you

Comment: `if(name != "END")` needs to be `if(!name.equals("END"))`

Comment: The problem is that your Scanner is only expecting one integer while you give more than one.

Comment: I change the name to if(!name.equals("END") and it worked with only one name. The problem seems to be when i add a first and last name with a space... ex Harry Morgan

Comment: You need !equals()...

Comment: @Jane use `nextLine()` instead of `next` to input the `name`

Comment: Err, I think your main problem is that you try to use a scanner without knowing how to use that in detail. But there are zillions of questions here and tutorials elsewhere that explain in great depth how to use a scanner. Have you tried that research thing?

Comment: You know, this is not a free debug service where we hold your hand fixing all the problems in your code with you updating your question with changes..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use `.next` to take the input of the name. Therefore, when you input

```
Harry Morgan
```

it treats **Harry** as the `name` and **Morgan** as the score. As **Morgan** cannot be represented as a `int`, you get the error.

To fix, use `nextLine` instead of `next`.

Also, your if statement is broken.Try

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter first, last name: ");
name = input.nextLine();
if(!name.equals("END"))
{
    while(score != -1)
    {
        System.out.print("Enter a score: ");
        score = input.nextInt();
        totalS = (totalS+score);
    }
}
```

Comment: There is more wrong. They are trying to provide numbers in list format when the Scanner is only scanning for 1 integer.

Comment: @AndrewLi I just fixed the obvious errors. We are not to do homework here. What needs to be implemented, is to be done by the OP and not us.